# SQL Query to select parent that has child records with different values in the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, inner-join, parent-child

This database has a one-to-many relationship where the parent table, Customers, is a list of customers and the child table, Orders, is a list of things they have bought. I'm trying to develop a query to select customers who have bought BOTH a television and a couch. The following query is returning 0 results.

```
SELECT Customer.*
FROM Customer
JOIN Orders
ON Customer.ID = Orders.customerID
WHERE Orders.item = 'television'
AND Orders.item = 'couch';
```

Replacing the AND with an OR doesn't work because it returns the customers who have bought both or just one of the items. My goal result is just the customers who have bought both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to leverage subqueries (or union) which flavor of sql are you using?

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ORDERS o WHERE c.id = o.id and type = 'couch')
  and EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ORDERS o WHERE c.id = o.id and type = 'tv')
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I hadn't even known about the 'EXISTS' statement. (I'm still new to MySQL.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a MySQL user but I have learned from SO that many queries can be slow. Here are options that only require a single subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER c
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT o.type) FROM ORDERS o
    WHERE o.id = c.id AND o.type IN ('couch', 'tv')
) = 2
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER c
WHERE c.id IN (
    SELECT o.id FROM ORDERS o
    WHERE o.type IN ('couch', 'tv')
    GROUP BY o.id
    HAVING MIN(o.type) <> MAX(o.type) -- or COUNT(DISTINCT o.type) = 2
)
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM CUSTOMER c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ORDERS o WHERE c.id = o.id and type IN ('tv','couch')) is another way to write the query

Comment: the line o.id=c.id will filter out any connecctions. the exists function helps you get by without the group by clauses and extra comparison.

Comment: @discosammy This is seven years old. But at a glance your first query is not equivalent. I'm fully aware of how to use `group by` and `exists`.